# Making an Obscure bit of Open-Sorcery Work

Tags: php, sql, drupal

I am attempting to use the rowing club boat booking system at https://github.com/erikroos/BIS, but have reached the end of my talent.

Logging into my installed system appears to be the problem. As I understand the problem, out of the 'box' it is set up to borrow the user login details from a Drupal database on the original creator's server.

Obviously, that won't work for me.

I suspect the changes must be made in:

```
function ValidateLogin($user, $pass, $database_host, $login_database_user, $login_database_pass, $login_database) {

    // Drupal-DB selecteren
    $link_drupal = mysql_connect($database_host, $login_database_user, $login_database_pass);
    if (!mysql_select_db($login_database, $link_drupal)) {
        echo mysql_error()."
";
    }

    $query = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='" . $user . "';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo mysql_error()."
";
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $pass_db = $row['pass'];
    mysql_close($link_drupal);
    $pass_given = md5($pass);
    if ($pass_db == $pass_given) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Attempting to login produces these errors: (all the line refs are within the above snippet)

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'whatl675_boat'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/whatl675/public_html/boats/include_helperMethods.php on line 95

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/whatl675/public_html/boats/include_helperMethods.php on line 96
Access denied for user 'whatl675_boat'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/whatl675/public_html/boats/include_helperMethods.php on line 101

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/whatl675/public_html/boats/include_helperMethods.php on line 101
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/whatl675/public_html/boats/include_helperMethods.php on line 105

Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/whatl675/public_html/boats/include_helperMethods.php on line 107
```

So what I need it to do is point instead to a table in the main database (which we can call 'boat' with the table 'users').

Thanks for reading this far (and please don't feel obliged to help),

WK

(Oh, almost forgot, it's conveniently entirely written in Dutch.)

Comment: Do you have any piece of code, any error, something to show? (apart from the whole library. Don't expect people to install it on _THEIR_ environment to guess what's wrong _FOR YOU_)

Comment: Its hard to know how to help when we dont really know the problem.

Comment: not a quesion as of now. consider editing to be more specific. If you want opinion, then it will be subjective and will be closed eventualy.

Comment: Are you connecting to a database hosted on another domain? If that's the case, might just be a permission issue (the db user hasn't the privileges to accept connection outside the allowed IPs)

Comment: No, it should all be on the same domain. There is a 'users' table in the system's database, but I suspect that it might be written such that it uses the users from an installation of Drupal. That feature, I think, was fairly specific to whoever wrote it - I don't have an installation of Drupal on the go to use.

Comment: So, what are the errors you're receiving?

Comment: I've added the errors above. (for reference, the top line of the upper code snippet is no 92)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that all you need to do is create a MySQL database with all the tables and columns that the application requires and edit the config variables ($database_host, $login_database_user, $login_database_pass). At that point you could change $link_drupal to say something less misleading like $link_mysql and debug from there.

It doesn't look too complicated after you get to that point by just looking at the errors.
Do all of that and post the results (remaining errors).

Do you know all of the fields/values that the database is going to require?
Let me know if I am way off track.

Comment: That sounds like a really good idea. I'm afraid I'm rather learning on the job, but I shall get to work on your plan. I wish I'd thought of that myself!

Comment: Errors gone - very nearly up and running. Now just to translate the whole lot to English, and I'm done. Thanks for the help.